# Giving rights to change permisions in linux

Tags: linux, sudoers

So, let's say that I have added a new user to my system, let's call it user.I want user to have the rights to change permisions(like chmod, chown, etc) to any other file on my system, without any pasword. What should I write in /etc/sudoers ? And also what should I write for rights like:

- rights to edit any conf file in /etc
- rights to restart all services(like networking) in my system

Answer (score 0):

Just add the user to the sudo group:

```
sudo adduser <username> sudo
```

Group membership is only evaluated upon login, so if the user is already logged in they'll have to log out and in before they can use their new permissions.

This works because /etc/sudoers is pre-configured to grant permissions to all members of this group (You should not have to make any changes to this):

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```